# multiple indexes same column sql

Tags: indexing, db2

For DB2 database, Consider Table `tbl` (`colA`, `colB`, `colC`) and queries as

```
select *
 from tbl
where tbl.colA = 1234.

select *
from tbl
where tbl.colA =1234
and tbl.colB = 73874
```

Will it help if we create two indexes i) on `colA`   ii) composite - `colA,colB`

if the above sql's are frequently accessed then will it help to have two indexes as above. Will the optemizer pick the correct index based on the query.

Comment: A composite index should be used for any queries that use any prefix of the index. So the second index would help both queries.

Answer (score 2):

You only need index (ii). A composite index is used whenever the search data is in a prefix of the columns. So an index on `colA,colB,colC,colD` will be used when you search `colA`, `colA and colB`, `colA, colB, and colC`, and `colA, colB, colC, and colD`.

Comment: In addition, It is important to put the right column order when creating the index. If index is ColB, ColA, then il will be used as index sargable, and that is not as efficient as ColA, ColB.

Comment: Extending the above by Barmar and AngocA, For composite index (COLA, COLB), if there is query select * from tbl where colB = 3456. Will it use index for this query.

Comment: No, if the WHERE clause doesn't use a prefix of the index, the index cannot be used for it at all. Think of a composite index as a tree structure -- you can't find the B's until you first select the A parents.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, AngocA for answering my questions. I understand indexing a little better now.

Comment: I guess I said the thank you's quite early. Can I have composite index as (cola,colb,colc) and (cola, cold, colc) and (colb,colc,cold).

Comment: You can have as many indexes as you want (if you have enough disk space), and the query optimizer should pick the one that matches the query best.